# a stochastic process question to compute expectation waiting time of all of passengers

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes

Hi friends: I have a question like following:
Assume that passengers arrive at a bus station as a Poisson process with rate
λ. The only bus departs after a deterministic time T. Let W be the combined waiting time for all passengers. Compute E[W](The expectation of he combined waiting time).

I am confused about this question. Someone know how to solve it？

Answer (score 1):

In a Poisson process, the interarrival times are exponential. Let $T_i$ be the interarrival time of the $i$th passenger, then $T_i \sim \mathcal{E}xp(\lambda)$. Therefore, his/her waiting time $W_i$ is
$$
W_i = (T - T_i)I_{[T_i \le T]}, 
$$
where $i=1,...,N$, such that $N \sim Poisson(\lambda)$ is the total number of arrivals in the interval $[0, T]$.The expected value of the combined waiting times $W$ is
$$
E[\sum_{i=1}^N W_i] = E(N)(T-E[T_i])P(T_i \le T) = \lambda ( T - 1/\lambda)( 1 - e^{-\lambda T}) 
$$